# How to search and match a particular word from 1st table in MySQL to 2nd table.

Tags: php, mysql

I am a learner and I am Developing a web application.
First I am Registering and storing values in a database in 1st table.
1st Table is registration table it Contains 3 columns and mobile is unique key in it

```
ID |   Name    | Mobile
---------------------------
1  |  Himanshu | 9411154321
---------------------------
2  |  Hunny    | 9997421931
---------------------------
```

Now 2nd Table named **message** also Contains 3 columns

```
ID |   Mobile    | Message
-------------------------------------
1  |  9411154321 | Hello 1st msg 
-------------------------------------
2  |  9999999999 | 2nd msg from another number
-------------------------------------
3  |  9411154321 | 3rd msg 
-------------------------------------
4  |  9999900000 | 4th msg
-------------------------------------
```

In the 2nd table there will be real time updation i.e in message table. I want to search is, the mobile number stored in 2nd table match with 1st table.
If match found in the 1st table then only it process further, otherwise it display an error.

I dont knw what query to use in PHP/ Mysql to match this.
Please help.

Comment: This is what you use joins for: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)
http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

Comment: @VyassaBaratham If you'd recommended [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) in an answer, I'd downvote it.

Comment: @AaronMiller Fair enough, but I actually didn't even look at any of the links I posted. I assumed that any reference would be able to describe something this basic.

Comment: @VyassaBaratham You'd think, right? Unfortunately, in the context of W3Schools.com, that is far from a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1):

My simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM second_table LEFT OUTER JOIN first_table
  ON first_table.Mobile = second_table.Mobile;
```

**More:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)